# Checking multiple URLs for content change at the same time

Tags: python, loops, python-requests, monitoring

How would I make this script grab URLs of a list (URLS=[]) and check all URLs at the same time?

`for i in range(len(URLs)):` i tried using for range loop but it's just test one after another, I want it to run multiple URLs at the same time.

```
PrevVersion = ""
FirstRun = True
url=""
while True:

   # download the page
   response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
   # parse the downloaded homepage
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

   # remove all scripts and styles
   for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
       script.extract()
   soup = soup.get_text()
   # compare the page text to the previous version
   if PrevVersion != soup:
       # on the first run - just memorize the page
       if FirstRun == True:
           PrevVersion = soup
           FirstRun = False
           print ("Start Monitoring "+url+ ""+ str(datetime.now()))
       else:
           print ("Changes detected at: "+ str(datetime.now()))
           OldPage = PrevVersion.splitlines()
           NewPage = soup.splitlines()
           # compare versions and highlight changes using difflib
           d = difflib.Differ()
           diff = d.compare(OldPage, NewPage)
           out_text = "\n".join([ll.rstrip() for ll in '\n'.join(diff).splitlines() if ll.strip()])
           print (out_text)
           OldPage = NewPage
           #print ('\n'.join(diff))
           PrevVersion = soup
   else:
       print( "No Changes "+ str(datetime.now()))
   time.sleep(10)
   continue
```

This script works but only one url

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all three you might need multithreading.
You should define a function and then call it with different threads.

Comment: Good idea, I tried it out but I can't manage to make them not check the same line at one point in my url list, how would you make them assign what url to read.